# Is there a way to replace a normal character list to a custom character list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
normal = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
          'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
          'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

modified = ['s', 'n', 'v', 'f', 'r', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'o', 'k', 'l', 'a',
          'z', 'm', 'p', 'q', 'w', 't', 'd', 'y', 'i', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'u', 'x']

word = input()

for char in word:
    if char in normal:
        char.replace(char, modified)
```

This is what i have so far,
I want to be able to type in a sentence and it will output the sentence with the modified alphabets

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: I'll look into that method. Much thanks!

Comment: Got it to work,
thank you very much kind stranger

Answer (score 0):

```py
normal = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

modified = 'lvxswdfguhjknbiopearycqztm'

word = input()

convert = str.maketrans(normal, modified)
print(word.translate(convert))
```

Comment: You can use `str.maketrans`, but if you define both alphabets inline it's probably better *(for performance)* to define translate table itself: `convert = {97: 'l', 98: 'v', 99: 'x', 100: 's', 101: 'w', 102: 'd', 103: 'f', 104: 'g', 105: 'u', 106: 'h', 107: 'j', 108: 'k', 109: 'n', 110: 'b', 111: 'i', 112: 'o', 113: 'p', 114: 'e', 115: 'a', 116: 'r', 117: 'y', 118: 'c', 119: 'q', 120: 'z', 121: 't', 122: 'm'}`

Comment: Please add an explanation, to make it more useful to future readers

Answer (score 0):

one of the way to map the normal list character with the modified list character and replace them in the sentence.

```
normal = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
          'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
          'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

modified = ['s', 'n', 'v', 'f', 'r', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'o', 'k', 'l', 'a',
          'z', 'm', 'p', 'q', 'w', 't', 'd', 'y', 'i', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'u', 'x']


mapper = {}

for a, b in zip(normal, modified):
    mapper[b] = a


word ="this is user commented word"

# new_word = ' '.join(map(lambda x: ''.join(mapper[i] for i in x), word.split()))

new_word = []
for i in word.split():
    tmp = []
    for j in i:
        tmp.append(mapper[j])
    new_word.append(''.join(tmp))


new_sentence = ' '.join(new_word)

print(new_sentence)
```

output

```
rgua ua yawe xinnwbrws qies
```

Comment: Wow. You reinvented the wheel, but it's square. **1.** `str` is also a sequence, you don't need to init `normal` and `modified` as lists *(also it consume much more memory)* **2.** you can easily init `mapper` with simple one-liner `mapper = dict(zip(normal, modified))` **3.** Look at first suggestion, you don't need lists there **4.** There's no reason to split string, it's just useless memory consumption. **Conclusion:** It's very bad example which consume 5 times more memory than required and use dozen of built-in functions ignoring `str.transate()` which actually do the job. **Downvoted.**